# Iterate over many Shopify liquid collections

Tags: shopify, liquid

Unbelievably, the `collections` global variable in Shopify's Liquid is paginated. How can I iterate over all the collections, or filter the results by an attribute? I've tried `paginate` which isn't suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't iterate over many collections using liquid.